# PHP - Adding an interval to dates and getting the difference not working

Tags: php

I want to have a countdown for how long until something expires, but it's not working. Specially, using the diff function of datetime returns essentially a dateinterval of nothing (all 0s). Here's the code:

```
    $created = new DateTime("2012-11-20");
    $expires = $created;
    $expires->add(new DateInterval("P14D")); //adds a week
    $timeLeft = $created->diff($expires);
    echo $timeLeft->format('%a days');
```

The problem is this code returns 0 days always..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is how you are copying the object, you need to clone the object instead .. replace

```
$expires = $created;
```

With

```
$expires = clone $created;
```

Full Code

```
$created = new DateTime("2012-11-20");
$expires = clone $created;
$expires->add(new DateInterval("P14D")); //adds 14 days
$timeLeft = $created->diff($expires);
echo $timeLeft->format('%a days');
```

Output

```
14 days
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/4216)